# Java Maven with DB2?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, db2

I created a java maven project in eclipse, and I need to access a DB2 database.  I have the latest version of the db2jcc.jar driver.  I am struggling to get this driver correctly installed via Maven.  Been all over the net looking for answers, havent found much.  I do not have the license for the db2jcc driver, if that matters.  I have an ant version of this project which works perfectly with my db2jcc driver.

Mostly recently, I tried the following in my maven project:

`mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2 -DartifactId=db2jcc -Dversion=unknown -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=db2jcc.jar`

The above command succeeded.

I then added the following to my pom.xml:

`<dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
        <version>unknown</version>
</dependency>`

I create a Connection in java, then a sql statement and when I try to issue a executeQuery command, I get the following error:

"Source not found  The JAR file M2_REPO/com/ibm/db2/db2jcc/unknown/db2jcc-unknown.jar has no source attachment.  You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below:"

How do I properly use the db2jcc driver with Maven and eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the db2jcc jar, but need to use it in Maven, you would need to either find that dependency in a public repository, or import the jar into a repository that you can use in your build.

Since it's an IBM jar, chances are that you're going to have to import it. [Look here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) for info about importing 3rd party jars into your local repository.

In order to do that, you'll need to include a real version of the driver (no, unknown isn't really an option). If you don't know the exact version, I've found that the easiest way to do that with most jars is to simply unzip them and look in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file.

After installing, the jar will be available for your local builds. Note that this will not be available for other members of your team, unless you can install the jar into a shared Maven repository that everyone uses.

Comment: I already took the steps for importing a third-party jar into the local repository.  In fact, I posted the command for doing so in my initial post:  mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2 -DartifactId=db2jcc -Dversion=unknown -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=db2jcc.jar

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cn.guoyukun.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cn.guoyukun.jdbc/db2jcc/1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

The DB2 java driver (Type 4 JDBC connector) has now (really for real) been published to maven central:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.db2/jcc

Include it as a dependency like so:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.db2/jcc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
    <version>11.1.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```